# How to connect to the internet through another PC?

Tags: networking, cluster

I have a small cluster with several nodes. Only one node (let's call it *root*), can connect to the internet. All nodes are connected, so we can ping from one to another, but we can't reach Internet from common node (i.e. not root).

#### Root node `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:d8:53:25  
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4084 errors:0 dropped:1295 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:249141 (243.3 KiB)  TX bytes:87110 (85.0 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:8d:12:54:75:aa  
          inet addr:158.184.27.129  Bcast:158.184.27.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:229772 (224.3 KiB)  TX bytes:68634 (67.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:260 (260.0 B)  TX bytes:260 (260.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:13:39:02:c3  
          inet addr:158.196.122.94  Bcast:158.196.123.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37269 (36.3 KiB)  TX bytes:27150 (26.5 KiB)
```

#### Root node `route -n` output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         158.184.27.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
158.184.27.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

#### Common node `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:b3:ed:0e  
      inet addr:192.168.10.11  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5078 errors:0 dropped:2249 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:287740 (280.9 KiB)  TX bytes:179477 (175.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3590 (3.5 KiB)  TX bytes:3590 (3.5 KiB)
```

#### Common node `route -n` output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.10   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Do you have any idea, how could I connect to the Internet from common node through the root node? I have very little knowledge of networking, so please, try to explain it in detail.

---

#### EDIT:

Considering Richard Neumann's answer, I enabled IP forwarding on the root node. And I think, that the root node already IS set as the default gateway (see Common node `route -n` output).

But the internet is still not working...

---

#### EDIT 2:

```
> traceroute 8.8.8.8
1 permonik0 (192.168.10.10) 0.972ms 0.957ms 0.922ms
2 * * *
...
30 * * *
```

---

#### EDIT 3:

I set NAT up according to [this article](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html) and now I can even ping 8.8.8.8 successfully. But still, I can't ping any website, so it looks, there is some remaining DNS problem now.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I added the output into my question

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If @Richard Neumann's answer did not work, there is a possibility of it being a DNS issue.

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Set up IP Forwarding and Masquerading.

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --jump MASQUERADE --source 192.168.10.10/24 
iptables-save > /root/clients.fw
echo "/sbin/iptables-restore < /root/clients.fw" >> /etc/rc.local
```

This above commands will enable IP Forwarding, and setup a firewall using `iptables` that allows you to access the internet from your client's.

Comment: Thank you, I added the line, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: What happens when you simply `ping 8.8.8.8`? @Eenoku

Comment: Ping doesn't work...

Comment: "Ping doesn't work" That does not help me at all. What does ping say?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry :-) Ping hangs, like it can't connect the address.

Comment: Ok, ping works, I've edited my question.

Comment: If ping works, append the `nameserver ...` line to `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: `nameserver 8.8.8.8` is appended both on the root node and the common one

Answer (score 2):

Your *root node* will have to act as a *router* for the other nodes.

You'll need to enable IP forwarding, in your case for IPv4, on the *router*:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

And to make it persistent, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

You'd probably also want to make the *router* the default gateway on the other *nodes*.

If the *next hop* beyond your *router* is not aware of the network 192.168.10.10/24, then you'll need to implement [Network Address Translation](https://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial) (*NAT*).
Have a look at `iptables` and its `MASQUERADE` option.

For possible DNS issues, see @Hunter.S.Thompson's answer.

Comment: Just to add. Run "sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" to make the change live and "sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf" to make the changes persistent after reboot.

Comment: `sysctl -p` *loads* the settings from `sysctl.conf`.

Comment: Thank you, I've made the changes and edited my question. But, it doesn't work yet

Comment: Could you, please, describe a little what do you mean by your last paragraph exactly?

Comment: Ok, NAT is set up, now I have  a problem with DNS probably... I've edited my question...